# SaltStack - Overriding and referencing Pillar value

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, amazon-ec2, salt-stack

I'm very new to saltstack and still learning so if there is a better way of doing things please let me know.

I'm trying to pass in override values and cascade use that override value in variable pillar files. So I plan to have a `default.sls` file that contains variables that all the other pillars will use. I want to also be able to override the `default.sls` variables from the command line.

Here is what I'm doing:

File structure:

```
/pillar/top.sls
/pillar/default.sls
/pillar/test.sls
```

In `/pillar/top.sls`

```
base:
'*':
    - default
'test':
    - match: glob
    - test
```

In `/pillar/default.sls`

```
{% set home_location = salt['cmd.shell']('eval echo "~ec2-user"') %}

environment: dev
uniqueid: all
side: a
region: myregion
app: myapp
ipaddress: {{ grains['ip4_interfaces']['eth0'][0] }}
hostname: {{ grains['host'] }}
homedir: {{ home_location }}
docker:
    - pip:
        - version: 4.0.2
```

In `/pillar/test.sls`

```
test:
- log:
    - group: logs-{{ pillar['environment'] }}-{{ pillar['uniqueid'] }}-{{ pillar['app'] }}
    - stream: logs_{{ pillar['side'] }}_mysupertest_{{ pillar['ipaddress'] }}
```

Here is the command I am running `locally` (masterless):

```
salt-call --id 'test' pillar.items --local pillar='{"environment":"uat","side":"b"}'
```

It throws the following error:

> SaltRenderError: Jinja variable 'salt.utils.context.NamespacedDictWrapper object' has no attribute 'environment'
>   [CRITICAL] Pillar render error: Rendering SLS 'test' failed. Please see master log for details.

So it's not getting the values from the `default.sls` file. What am I doing wrong?

Also I have tried adding the following to the `test.sls` file with the same results:

```
include:
- pillar://default
```

Comment: Why do you want to use the tool saltstack?

Comment: * Can be run masterless

* written in python

* Open source

* Large community

* Very extensible 

* Makes infrastructure code readable

* Tons of pre build functions/modules

* easy to navigate docs

All that stuff is great but if I can't cascade my environment name down to other configurations then this tool becomes useless. For example the logs will be different between environments but everything else will remain the same. Also allowing to override the logs to send to a custom log location during testing. Can't really do this if my overrides arn't cascaded.

Comment: I still use salt-stack. But I would use ansible the next time I could start from scratch.